# More elegant way to call getter within deeply nested data classes

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I have deserialized a huge XML file and that leaves me with a lot of (nested) data classes. I'm looking for a more elegant way to do calls to specific getters within these objects. So I would rather not fill my code with all these dot calls.

I have to set quite some fields to return a new Model, which currently looks something like this (I made up the model for this question):

```
        return TestClass(
    appointmentDate = message.data.appointment.appointmentDescription.AppointmentDetails.appointmentDate
    appointmentX = message.data.appointment.appointmentDescription.X.Y.Z
    appointmentY = message.data.appointment.appointmentDescription.AppointmentDetails.X.Y.Z
    appointmentZ = message.data.appointment.Z
    )
```

I know I could do val appointmentDescription = message.data.appointment.appointmentDescription and do my calls from there to shorten it a bit, but there must be a shorter and better way I assume.

Does anyone know a way to do this in a more elegant and clean way? I'm pretty new to Kotlin and it is quite hard for me to properly lookup any solutions on the internet since I can't find any and am probably searching for the wrong things.

Comment: What would your proposal be for a shorter way to access a nested structure other than by using a `.` in any language?

Comment: as you mentioned XML, maybe you want to use something like XPath or XQuery instead of deserializing everything? With XPath, for example, you could use `//Z` to return all `Z` elements in the XML regardless of its parent...

Comment: Maybe im missing something, but why not simply pass `message.data.appointment` as a whole? \

Answer (score 0):

Try the `with` function:

```
data class Message (val data: Data)
data class Data (val appointment: Appointment)
data class Appointment(val appointmentDescription: AppointmentDescription)
data class AppointmentDescription(val x: Int, val appointmentDetails: AppointmentDetails)
data class AppointmentDetails(val x:Int, val y:Int)

fun TestClass(message: Message) {
    with(message.data.appointment.appointmentDescription) {
        val appointmentX = x
        val appointmentY = appointmentDetails.y
    }
}
```

This should be useful: https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84